# JUniting simple user input?

Tags: java, junit

I want to make a JUnit testclass which tests a very simple method.

```
public static String whatsYourName() {
  System.out.println("Input your name:");
  yourName = in.next(); 
  return yourName;
}.
```

My Question was regarded to how you could test a simple methode as above stated.
I think the below solution is perfect!

Comment: There is no question here...

Comment: What is `in`? You could provide your own inputstream that provides a known data and check that the method returns the expected output.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: This code is untestable and testing such things has no sense at all.

Comment: Why do you think that MariuszS? I think assylias proved quite opposite down under

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first change the method to take the Scanner as an argument (dependency injection principles):

```
public static String whatsYourName(Scanner in) {
  System.out.println("Input your name:");
  yourName = in.next(); 
  return yourName;
}
```

Then it becomes easy to test:

```
@Test public void testName() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner("my name");
    assertEquals("my name", whatsYourName(in));
}
```

Now that only tests that your method extract the right information from the Scanner, it does not test that a user can actually input something - but that would be part of your integration tests, not unit tests.

Also note that your method is essentially equivalent to `return in.next();` so **you are actually testing the `next` method of `Scanner`, which is unnecessary**. But if the method beocmes more complex the principle will apply.

A very interesting piece to read: [Google guide on Writing Testable Code](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf).

Comment: Awesome work.
You just took my from clueless about JUnit to atleast understanding it fairly :)
Thanks

Comment: I took the test and it failed because .next only takes next token :)